# BroadcastReceiver not being called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have some problems. I want to transfer messages. I use  context.sendBroadcast to send and BroadcastReceiver - to receive messages

```
public class GPS_module implements LocationListener {

private Context context;

public GPS_module(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx; 
        manager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }
.....

 public void sendMessage(String str) {
       Intent intent = new Intent("logGPS");
       intent.putExtra("Message",str);
       context.sendBroadcast(intent);
} 

}
```

for receiving messages  I use the following source code

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment{
    .......
    @Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_panel_1, null);

            BroadcastReceiver log = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
                {
                    if(intent.getAction().equals("logGPS"))
                    {
                        myLog(intent.getStringExtra("Message"));

                    }
                }
            };

            return myFragmentView ;

          }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like:

(This is for Connectivity)

```
   registerReceiver(myReceiver,
           new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

You need to register and set an intent filter.

Comment: registerReceiver(log,new IntentFilter("logGPS")); does not work for onCreateView (fragment)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134203/how-to-use-registerreceiver-method

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your receiver? I don't see this in your code.

Comment: No, not registered, I do not know the sequence - that's all there is