# How to disable/enable android receiver in source code?

Tags: android, receiver, bootcompleted

I hava a question about Android Receiver.
I'm possible to change System app.
B is the first app, when user turns on the power. But the problem is when user chooses FACTORY Mode(like setting language, google id...), B App has to be started finishing A App setting. That's why use android:enabled="false"and A App trigger B app. But not working.

I think "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" send just one time after booting, so after changing enable receiver B app, it's not working. Is it right? 
Please can you give me some advise?

A App

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ComponentName compName = new ComponentName("com.test.myapp", "com.test.myapp.receiver");
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(compName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);
```

B App AndoidManifest.xml

```
<receiver 
    android:name="com.test.myapp.receiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

B App

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
       Intent startMainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, new.class);
       startMainActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(startMainActivityIntent);
}
```

Comment: You can use default method `registerReceiver()` & `deregisterReceiver`. For more info see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134203/how-to-use-registerreceiver-method

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just start app B from app A directly? Yes, boot completed triggered only once. But you can start app B without any receivers, [look here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)